# OCL bond on operation between two classes

Tags: class, constraints, diagram, class-diagram, ocl

I have a class diagram and I need to write some OCL about it but I'm not sure about the right syntax. I've searched a lot and found a lot of different ways, so I'd like to know if the way I'm going to write them is correct.

For example, in my class diagram I have the classes `Ticket` and `Event` linked by the role `ticket validFor event`. The ticket has a `price` attribute which is `float`. Is this way correct to write OCL to calcualte the total incoming of an event?

```
CONTEXT Event::totalIncoming():float
post result=ticket.allInstances()->select(t : t.validFor=self)->collect(price)->sum()
```

I'm taking all insances of tickets, selecting all instances valid for the event, collecting their prices and finally summing them.

Answer (score 1):

The example you provide uses Complete OCL; a self standing text document, often with a `*.ocl` file extension in which an Essential OCL expression is given a surrounding context as indicated by Section 12 of the OCL specification: "The Use of OCL Expressions in UML Models". This approach is helpful if you want to separate your constraint and model concerns and/or exploit the utility of bulk text editing.

Alternatively you may use a tool that provides a text box for each UML Constraint. In this case you often enter just an Essential OCL expression that the tool wraps up in an appropriate way as a Constraint.body.

If working with Ecore, you may use OCLinEcore to embed Essential OCL expressions within the `*.ecore` or `*.oclinecore`.

You example is wrong in that you should use lower case `context`, and a `:` and optionally a name after `post`.

Your example is probably wrong in that you use `ticket` rather than `Ticket` the class name.

Your example is undesirable in that you use `allInstances` which should be avoided wherever possible if you actually plan to execute the OCL.

However perhaps you did mean `ticket` as the collection member variable, in which case the `allInstances()` is wrong. `ticket->select(...)` is sufficient to select some of the ticket collection.

I suspect that `result = ticket->select(validFor=self).price->sum()` would do. However the reverse testing of `validFor` could be redundant since the forward navigation is often sufficient with a check of the reverse navigation redundant.